# Java API - Bulk Payments started failing

Tags: paypal-rest-sdk

So a little over a week ago I was able to make a number of bulk payouts using the rest api for Java but, this week they are all returning 500 errors. Since I  was successful last week I was hoping this was a simple api change because  a new java sdk was released right after my successful test run but moving to the 1.1.2  version hasn't resolved my problem.  I've tried making a payment to different accounts now with no luck. Due to the feedback I'm getting here I'm not sure how to go about debugging this since the error message implies that this is entirely outside my control.

ANY suggestions would be greatly appreciated, I'm 2 days from going live and up until today I thought every thing was go to go.

```
com.paypal.base.rest.PayPalRESTException: Error code : 500 with response : {"name":"INTERNAL_ERROR","message":"An internal service error has occurred.","debug_id":"013d35b1dd3f6","information_link":"https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/#INTERNAL_ERROR"}
```

Comment: As a follow up I tried to execute this using the curl example and this also fails with a 500.

Comment: And 2 days later it started working with no intervention on my part. If you ever have problems with the sandbox.. it may not be your code...